# How to disable an S3 bucket redirect rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 bucket that's hosting a Vue application which uses Vue Router with history mode enabled. Originally, I had the following redirect rule in place to work around S3 not being able to resolve "virtual" routes (based on [this](https://medium.com/@BjornKrols/how-to-enable-history-mode-for-aws-s3-hosted-vue-applications-3bf40d51d9a7) approach). It prefixes the path with a hash syntax which a script on the page identifies and strips, using `history.pushState()` to turn it back into a non-hashed path that history mode can understand.

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>mydomain.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>#!/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

However, the more modern approach is to just let CloudFront do it by pointing `403` and `404` error pages at `/index.html` (based on [this](https://keita.blog/2015/11/24/hosting-a-single-page-app-on-s3-with-proper-urls/) approach).

After setting up the CloudFront error pages, I've removed the redirect rule from the bucket and even the error document from the bucket. However, S3 continues to use the redirect rule and prefix my routes with `#!/`.

How can I force the redirect rule to stop operating?

Comment: Did CloudFront cache the redirects before you removed them?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I invalidate my CloudFront cache on the index.html each time and all the builds from vue are hashed. The behaviour of adding the `#!` to the path still remains, though.

Comment: You need to invalidate `/*` rather than `index.html`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that was it. Can you make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudFront invalidations work against the path the browser is actually requesting, not the path being requested from the origin (back-end) server.

Invalidating `/` would probably have worked in this case, but `/*` invalidates everything.  Using `/index.html` (the console invisibly adds the leading `/` if you don't) would only clear the cache in the case where the *browser* was directly requesting `/index.html`.

CloudFront accepts invalidation requests even when they don't match anything, because an invalidation request is essentially a directive to *ensure that no matching objects are in the cache*.  When the invalidation request completes, then that condition is true -- there are, at that point, no matching objects.  Regardless of whether they were purged or were never there, the invalidation request can be said to have succeeded, because they are now gone... but a side effect of this is that you don't get a warning if you invalidate something that was never there.